# How to insert jquery datepicker on iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, datepicker

So I have my function (using ajax):

```
function show_statsDays($element,$id)
{
    $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
    $tpl = new PHPTAL();
    $tpl->setTemplate('templates/lightboxes/statsDays.tpl.xhtml');

    $data = array();

    /*Enregistrement du nombre d'acces par mois dans un tableau*/
    $objDatabase = QApplication::$Database[1];
}
```

What I want to do, is to insert a datepicker (Jquery) on the iframe, I give to my function

```
($tpl->setTemplate('templates/lightboxes/statsDays.tpl.xhtml');
```

My iframe (statsDays.tpl.xhtml) is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="erreur">
    <div onclick="paper.clear();im_lightbox.close();" id="im_lightbox_coverpage" >
    </div>
    <div style="padding:10px; display:none; width:700px; height:550px; margin-top:-275px;" id="im_lightbox_container">
        ...
        <div class="navig_stats">
            <ul>                                
            ... 
               <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#datepickerMois").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}.onSelect:function(xajax_show_statsMonth));;
                    });
                </script>   
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: In an another folder,`templates/lightboxes/statsDays.tpl.xhtml`
And the page, where i launch the function show_stats is 
`http://localhost/PlateformeWeb/trunk/htdocs/marqueurs.php `
So we have `http://localhost/PlateformeWeb/trunk/htdocs/ templates/lightboxes/statsDays.tpl.xhtml,`

Comment: I meant "where the `<iframe>`-tag in your page? Could you show the snippet, please?